# How can i get SharedPeferance key:value form service class in MainActivity class

Tags: android

How can I get SharedPeferance key:value form service class in MainActivity class.
I am passing shared peferance object to mainactivity form service but i am getting null value.

Comment: can you post your code + error please ?

Comment: i dont get you, does it mean that you are passing `android.content.SharedPreferences` object from your service to your activity? how?

Answer (score 0):

You would never pass a shared preference object between two contexts.  SharedPreferences write to a file, just so they can be permanent.  You'd create a new SharedPreference in the Activity and read in the key by name.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general format of getting them back,still if you cant access them  post your code and modify question,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("YourSharedPreferences",     Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  
String Get_Value = prefs.getString(key, "");
```